# How to use node js and python on same domain?

Tags: python-2.7, express, webapp2

I have created my project in python (Webapp2), but i want to create admin panel in node js and set it in same directory.

I am facing problem how to route node app.js from url

Answer (score 1):

**Docker is the best option.**
Use docker and create three container (nginx, nodejs, Webapp2).

```
for nodejs, use port like 8080
for Webapp2, use port like 8000
```

> links nodejs and Webapp2 with ngninx in docker-compose.yml and configure nginx.conf file.

Use nginx.conf like

```
location /dashboard {
    proxy_pass http://nodejs:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
location / {
    proxy_pass http://webapp2:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.
If i want to deploy both node js and webapp2 on google cloud app engine,
then how i will manage?
e.g
http://lynkweb-165106.appspot.com/

i have this domain how i will run both node js and python code over it

Thanks

Comment: How i will use both python and node js on same domain on google app engine?